# Debugging Go (golang) code in Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, go

What is the best method of debugging go code in Windows?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514122/201618 states the GBD cannot be used as

> Windows and ARM binaries do not contain DWARF debugging information and, as such, cannot be inspected with GDB.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405768/201618 implies that the best thing to do is just use `fmt.Println`

Is there a better current option?  Is there a better planned future option?

Comment: there is like mingw gdb for windows, maybe that would work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492509/does-any-golang-interactive-debugger-exist/38471807#38471807

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to GDB you can use [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/go.html). Also, take a look to [comparison of IDEs for Google Go](http://geekmonkey.org/articles/20-comparison-of-ides-for-google-go).

Comment: I'm currently using Eclipse/goclipse, so would prefer a solution that wouldn't require me changing IDE.  However, will also take a look and see whether Zeus is a sensible solution.

Comment: If you actually build the Go compiler from source using the build batch file provided, this will update the debug information to match the source code found on the machine. This has the added benefit that you can step into the Go libraries and even step into the underlying C code found at the core of Go itself.

Answer (score 5):

LiteIDE (https://github.com/visualfc/liteide) includes a build of GDB that works on Windows.  When I experimented with Goclipse, I was able to point it to that GDB executable and debug applications just fine.

Comment: Can you please guide me in enabling debug in goclipse in windows?@Steve

Answer (score 2):

[Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/installation/windows/install.md) supports windows and can be installed with the following command:

```
go get github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
```

It has [integration](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/EditorIntegration.md) with code editors and IDEs such as VS code, Atom and IDEA. No Sublime Text support is available yet though!

Comment: Current package name is updated: `github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv`

Comment: Also note that delve only supports 64-bit architectures, at least by the time of writing this comment.