# In Go - anything like a NOP (assembler) command?

Tags: go

When debugging i often need to put a conditional breakpoint, ex :

```
if messageType == 1 {
 nop;  // <-- breakpoint
}
```

There is no 'nop' command and am fairly used to just put a dummy line in which is doing, ex :

```
if messageType == 1 {
 x = 1;  // <-- breakpoint
}
```

And then put the breakpoint at the line with x = 1.

Issue is in Go the compiler often starts battling me because im not using x etc - and am just wondering if theres a quick and smarter way of doing it with a oneline statement ? what do you guys do ?

Comment: Can't you set a break point assigning to a blank identifier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug a program written in the Go language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3400702/3415984)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't store it in a real variable:

```golang
if messageType == 1 {
 _ = 1
}
```